# Telerik Kendo Angular, icons not showing after update

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik

I updated Telerik to version 14.

After this, the icons are not shown, although the svg icons are displayed.
What could be the problem?
Before this everything worked.
Maybe something with the font or license that I don't have?

Styles `.k-i-...` are missing in the "Elements" tab of the browser.

```html
<button (click)="refresh()">
  <kendo-icon name="refresh"/>
</button>
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.8",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.8.5",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.1.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^16.3.0",
    "@ngrx/eslint-plugin": "^16.3.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^16.3.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-indicators": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-menu": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-navigation": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.7.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-fluent": "^7.0.1",
```

angular.ts

```
"styles": [
  {
    "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-fluent/dist/all.css"
  },
  "src/styles.less",
  "src/kendo.less",
  "src/assets/fonts/OpenSans/open-sans.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all packages were updated using ncu, I restored the previous version of the theme in package.json.

Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

With v14 font icons are no longer delivered with the Kendo UI theme. [This is mentioned in the docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/icons/#toc-setup). There is now a Kendo Font Icons npm package.